# onLocationChanged Is not Called While trying to Add marker to my Activity?

Tags: android, dictionary, location

I am useing this code to add marker in my Activity , but The onLocationChanged Is not called and for that I could not place marker here..

I am getting all the Toasts without the Toast without the onLocationChanged one.

I have tried every possible what to fix it up , but its just showing the Map there is no market nothing . Do i done any wrong import . Please suggest me way to fix it .

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Create", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Pause", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map Ready", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                        this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e("+++CONNECTION FAILED", "CONNECTION FAILED");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Change", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker

        Log.e("+++LOCATION CHANGE", "LOCATION CHANGE");

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        Log.e("+++LATI", location.getLatitude() + "====");
        Log.e("+++LONGI", location.getLongitude() + "====");

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.person_icon));


        LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(23.809591, 90.367447);
        LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(23.873751, 90.396454);
        LatLng latLng3 = new LatLng(23.746466, 90.376015);

        MarkerOptions markerOptions1 = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions1.position(latLng1);
        markerOptions1.title("Mirpur");
        markerOptions1.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_one));


        MarkerOptions markerOptions2 = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions2.position(latLng2);
        markerOptions2.title("Uttora");
        markerOptions2.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_two));


        MarkerOptions markerOptions3 = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions3.position(latLng3);
        markerOptions3.title("Dhanmondi");
        markerOptions3.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_three));


        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions1);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions2);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions3);

        //move map camera
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));

    }


    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

}
```

In the Manifest I have taken all kind of permission regrading this Location

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"></uses-permission-sdk-23>

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBm43jiOe04Qkb1NpsZAq1ryj_bfYsRXww" />


        <activity android:name=".MapsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TermsAndCondition"
            android:theme="@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" />
        <activity android:name=".ForgetPassword"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Need Immediate help. Cant get rid of It .

Comment: code looks fine.. but did u check whether code goes to `onConnected` method's if statement? Try to print log there..

Comment: onConnected is fine ...its adding the markers from there .. I have tried that . But i need to pin my location .. Which i could not .

Comment: What I mean is `onLocationChanged` method will get called only if you have a trigger of `requestLocationUpdates` method and that method is inside the if statement in onConnected method so make sure it actually goes inside if statement..